# Meaning of (96,) while using np.shape()?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I was trying to read data from a file using pandas and practicing numpy operations on the columns but when I tried to find the shape  of the column it is showing (96,). What does (96,) mean ?

```
df=pd.read_csv("ex2.txt")
df.columns=["X","Y","Final"]
np.shape(df["Y"])
```

The answer I am getting for this is :

```
(96,)
```

what does it mean?

Comment: There is always a documentation with every python package. Please look over there, before asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

It Means your column has 96 elements and is in fact, as expected, just a 1D array.

Source: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html

Answer (score 0):

adding to answer by @MrShadowjockey.

If you want to use the numpy array
you can covert the array (n,) to (n,1) using reshape function.

```
Y = df["Y"].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)
```

Else answer by @MrShadowjockey is sufficient.